# meaningless mutations while running mutation testing with Stryker

Tags: javascript, mutation-testing, stryker

I am new to mutation testing. I use the Stryker library to generate and to run tests. But some mutations break the whole logic between code expressions. For example,

// real code

```
if (!(typeof age == 'number' && Math.trunc(age) == age)) throw new Error('age must be a whole number');
```

// mutated code from Stryker

```
if (!(true && Math.trunc(age) == age)) throw new Error('age must be a whole number');
```

If `typeof age == 'number'` is false `Math.trunc(age) == age` is never executed because of shortcut And operator `&&`.
But Stryker creates a mutant which assumes that `Math.trunc(age) == age` must be executed when `typeof age == 'number'` is `false` and some test cases must fail.

Is this situation normal? What should I do in this situation? Should I ignore the mutant?

Thanks.